# Bind json data to dropdownlist in Webix

Tags: json, webix, webix-treetable

I have one API which return json data. I want to bind "id" and "first_name" in dropdownlist view using Webix? 
Please suggest me how to bind data?

Below is my code and json sample data.

```
webix.ajax("https://reqres.in/api/users", function (text, data) {

                                    webix.message(text.json()); //verify data
                                        });
```

Sample json data.
   {"page":1,"per_page":3,"total":12,"total_pages":4,"data":[{"**id**":1,"**first_name**":"George","last_name":"Bluth","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"},{"id":3,"first_name":"Emma","last_name":"Wong","avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"}]}

Answer (score 1):

You can load data like

```
var data = webix.ajax("https://reqres.in/api/users");
```

and later use it in combo | richselect

```
webix.ui({ view:"combo", options:{ data: data }})
```

As your data doesn't have "value" property, you need to define which values to render in the control, it can be done like next

```
view:"combo", options:{
body:{
    data:data,
    scheme:{
        $init: obj => {
            obj.value = obj.first_name +" "+ obj.last_name
        }
    }
}
}
```

https://snippet.webix.com/33t0xbnz